# Read delimited text (without newlines) and tell how many columns

Tags: r, import, data.table, newline, delimiter

I have several hundred text delimited files.  In some columns, a newline before the end of the row appears in random columns.  When is try to read, it looks for the correct number of columns, but because it is split on to the next row.

the arg `fill=T` does not help because it creates empty incorrect columns.

If I have:

```
"Aa|Bb|C\nc\ntwo|three|four"
```

But really should be two rows by three columns:

```
"Aa|Bb|Cc\ntwo|three|four"
```

How can I get there for all rows of the data (the error occurs randomly throughout)?

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have `C\nc` in the string, which introduces `c` to a new line. I guess you need to ensure the format of your input string as the first step, otherwise it is difficult to fixed via post-processing.

I am not sure if the code below is what you are after. Do you mean something like using `read.csv`?

```
read.csv(text = sub("\n","",s),sep = "|",header = FALSE)
```

which gives

```
   V1    V2   V3
1  Aa    Bb   Cc
2 two three four
```

---

If you are using `data.table`, you can try `fread` (thank @akrun)

```
fread(sub("\n", "", s))
```

**Data**

```
s <- "Aa|Bb|C\nc\ntwo|three|four"
```

Comment: @akrun Thanks! Added your solution :)

Comment: This works with a single line of data.  The embedded \n within a column does not happen in every row of the data.  So the sub() takes out the valid \n.  The trick is to find the \n before all delimiters are present in each row.